# Алгоритм построения календарной сетки

Tags: алгоритм

В общем, пользователь вводит любой год и в итоге получает календарь на заданный год. Код программы есть, все работает. Проблема заключается в понимании самого принципа/алгоритма построения этой календарной сетки.

Помогите кто чем может, Пожалуйста :3

Comment: то есть, код генерирует эту календарную сетку нужно вида/типа/формата? Тогда изучайте код. Или показывайте код.

Comment: да, именно так. 
Код оочень длинный, 386 строк

Comment: ага, и другие люди должны угадать, что именно там в этих 386 строках? Или это секретный код? выложите на любой paste.org/fpaste и подобных сервисах.

Comment: оригинально - выложить html код в вордовском документе.

Но похоже, что код либо малость обсфуцирован (но верю мало в это), либо писан незадачливым программистом.

По коду - делают хитрые расчеты, что бы рассчитать первый день года, а потом, можно будет собственно делать вывод.

А ещё - старый стиль работает плохо. В 1582 году он выдает совсем не то.

Answer (score 1):

Один мой товарищ очень хорошо разбирается в чужих исходниках такого плана, вот его страница, обращайтесь: https://vk.com/paulgrish ;)